# Mozilla Firefox block all connections to third-party resources?

Tags: javascript, css, browser, mozilla

I have web project which is written in *Play Framework (Scala)*.

I have strange behavior in **Mozilla Firefox** browser. It block all *CSS* and *Javascript* files which was located from other resources. For example here below you can see DevTool of Mozilla Firefox browser.

[image]

It seems like Mozilla Firefox block all connections to third-party resources by default.
In the same time other browsers like Google Chrome, Opera don't have such problem and works fine.

Also in Mozilla Firefox I disabled checkboxes inside Settings > Security.

I use **Mozilla FireFox version 63.0.1 (64 bit)**

I set CSS in the head tag as usually.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">
</head>
```

In `application.conf` file I set:

```
play.filters.headers {
  contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self';"
  contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" img-src 'self';"
  contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com use.fontawesome.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com;"
  contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" font-src 'self' use.fontawesome.com;"
  contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' code.jquery.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com code.highcharts.com;"
  contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" connect-src 'self';"
}
```

What would you advise to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: 0.50.1 is definitely not the version of Firefox you have; please check again.

Comment: Can you check if there are any CSP Headers sent?

Comment: @Lithilion I set some `contentSecurityPolicy` in `application.conf` file. Check my post again please. Where exactly I can see CSP headers?

Comment: @Ry- I delete Mozilla Firefox browser and install last actual version from official website. In settings of browser I see that version is `63.3.1 (64 bit)`.

Comment: or do you mean 63.0.1 - since that's the latest release

Comment: @Bravo yes, you are right! Version is `63.0.1`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: In the network monitor. You click on a file and you see the request and response headers

Comment: In `DevTool` of browser I open network section. I click to `bootstrap.min.css` file. Then it show me request header. You can see it in post.

Comment: check the main file (prob. html) and the response header

Comment: @Lithilion can you check my post again pls. I add new picture.